# Update Ubuntu 20.04 to libxml++ 3.0

Tags: package-management, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 contains libxml++-2.6, which in combination with gcc 11 gives auto_ptr depreciated. Other distributions already deliver libxml++ version 3.0
Please update the Ubuntu repository with a higher version of libxml++

Comment: Here part of the output of the apt show command: Package: libxml++2.6-dev:i386
Version: 2.40.1-3build1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: libxml++2.6
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
APT-Sources: http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages

Comment: The folks to ask would be the [Debian Gnome Maintainers Team](https://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-gnome-maintainers/). They are the folks who uploaded 2.6. Note that their primary goal is Gnome compatibility. You are also welcome, of course, to volunteer to become a Debian packager and [upload it yourself](http://mentors.debian.net). Most packages are uploaded by Debian volunteers.